# Installing Swampy Step by Step

Tags: python, package, swampy

I'm a novice at programming and am reading the book 'Think Python.'
In Chapter 4 I need to install 'swampy'- the python package. I have been trying for the past few days with no luck. I am running both Python 2.7 and 3.2. My computer runs Windows 7 and is 64 bit.

Please could someone provide me with simple step by step instructions as to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html) instruction?

Please try following it and write which step fails on your setup.

Or try following approach:

Assuming your Python 2.7 is installed in `C:\Python27`, open command prompt and type:
`C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe swampy`

Comment: Yes, But I got so confused on what to do. It didn't work when I typed python setup.py install. It gave me a syntax error.@Abgan

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the bottom part of your answer. It did work. Thankss. Do you have a link to explain the theory behind Computer Science? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you. Now I'm puzzled with your second question. Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science#Areas_of_computer_science and go on reading and studying. There's a whole new world waiting for you to discover.